# Optional packages in setuptools using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

Say I have a project like this:

```
pyproject.toml
src/
    cool/
        __init__.py
        ...
    cool_cli/
        __init__.py
        ...
```

I would like to be able do the following installs:

```
pip install cool  # 1
pip install cool[cli] #2
```

#1 is intended package and distribute just the `cool` package, whereas #2 would distribute both `cool` and `cool_cli`. Is this possible using `pyproject.toml` and setuptools? I can't see an obvious way of doing it.

```
[project]
name = "cool"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
version = "0.0.1"
readme = "readme.md"

dependencies = [
   "httpx"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
cli = [
    "click"
]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["cool", "cool_cli"]
```

Comment: There is no way to have optional **packages**, only optional **dependencies**. You need to split your distribution into two separate distributions and declare one (`cool_cli`) as an optional dependency for the other (`cool`).